# How do I change top header background color

Tags: headers

Please refer to website: https://virginiafrank.com
I cannot get the top header background color (or phone numbers) to change color. I would prefer the background gold and text black. I can't make that work either. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may please add following in your style.css

```
.l-subheader.at_top {
    background: gold !important;
    color: #000!important;
}
```

Please check it and let me know if it working thanks.

Comment: you just exchanged the colours. background:gold; color: #000; should be in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Pratik bhatt - The code you gave will only change the background color as the li has a separate color property. Will need to add the following.

```
.top-haed ul li {
 color: #000 !important;
}

.top-haed ul li  a {
 color: #000 !important;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.